# What is the best way to hide jQuery UI autocomplete if no input box is used?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have successfully attached autocomplete to the span tag with click event handler via

```
$('#myspan').click(function() {
 var target = $('#myvalue');
 $(this).autocomplete({
                minLength:0,                
                source: ['Apple','Banana','Strawberry'],
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    target.html(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
 $(this).autocomplete("search","");   
});​
```

The problem is, since there is no input box, no blur() event occurs and autocomplete remains on the screen if user clicks outside of the selector.
To see the effect, click subsequently on "Select first", then "Select second" without actually choosing an item: http://jsfiddle.net/gtcZb/

Comment: Sorry! All of jsfiddle it seems to be offline. Wasn't me, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you just make your span focusable? Addind a `tabindex` attribute to it will make it focusable (if you don't want it gaining focus through Tab and Shift+Tab, use `"-1"` as value).

I couldn't run your example (jsFiddle seems to be offline), but I tried to reproduce it and made it work - mostly:

HTML

```
<span id="myspan" tabindex="-1">abcd</span>
<span id="myvalue"></span>
```

JavaScript

```
 $('#myspan').click(function() {
     var target = $('#myvalue');
     $(this).autocomplete({
                    minLength:0,                
                    source: ['Apple','Banana','Strawberry'],
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        target.html(ui.item.value);
                    }
                })
     $(this).autocomplete("search","").focus();
 }).blur(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     setTimeout(function() { $this.autocomplete("close") },0);
 });​
```

<strike>It's not perfect - sometimes the autocomplete doesn't disappear, even when the span loses focus, and I couldn't figure out why. But it's a start...</strike>

Edit: I forgot the setTimeout closure... Now it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I just came up with... maybe someone will not be able to use tabIndex (see @mgibsonbr answer), although blur() is a bit nicer:

```
$('#myspan').click(function() {
     $(this).autocomplete({
                    ...same as in question...
                })
     $(this).autocomplete("search","").focus();
     //ensure autocomplete hides when user clicks somewhere else:
     var _self = $(this);
     setTimeout(function() { $('body').one("click",function(e) {
                                _self.autocomplete("close");
                });
     }, 0);
 });​
```